# RoR sum column of datetime type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm calculating total "walk time" for dog walking app. The Walks table has two cols, start_time and end_time. Since I want to display total time out for ALL walks for a particular dog, I should just be able to sum the two columns, subtract end_times_total from start_time_totals and result will be my total time out. However I'm getting strange results. When I sum the columns thusly,

start_times = dog.walks.sum('start_time')

end_times = dog.walks.sum('end_time')

BOTH start_times and end_times return the same value. Doing a sanity check I see that my start and end times in the db are indeed set as I would expect them to be (start times in the morning, end times in the afternoon), so the sum should definitely return a different value for each of the columns. Additionally, the value is different for each dog and in line with the relative values I would expect, so dogs with more walks return larger values than dogs with fewer walks. So, it looks like the sum is probably working, only somehow returning the same value for each column.

Btw, running this in dev Rails 3.2.3, ruby 2.0, SQLite.

Comment: Off topic: upgrade to the latest rails 3.2.13 - major security issues below that version

Answer (score 2):

Don't think that summing datetimes is a good idea. What you need is calculate **duration** of each single walk and sum them. You can do it in 2 ways:

#### 1. DB-dependent, but more efficient:

```
# sqlite in dev and test modes    
sql = "strftime('%s',end_time) - strftime('%s',start_time)" if !Rails.env.production? 
# production with postgres
sql = "extract(epoch from end_time - start_time)" if Rails.env.production? 

total = dog.walks.sum(sql)
```

#### 2. DB-agnostic, but less efficient in case of hundreds record for each dog:

```
total = dog.walks.all.inject(0) {|tot,w| tot+=w.end_time-w.start_time}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how sqlite handles datetime and operations on this data type, but while playing in sqlite console, I noticed that I could get reliable effects when converting datetime to seconds.

I would write it like:

```
dog.walks.sum("strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time)")
```

Query should look like:

```
select sum(strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time)) from walks;
```